# SQL Server transaction fails and table gets locked

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My stored procedure is like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Bid_Create]
    @BidType int,
    @ClientId int,
    @BidDate date,
    @EmailNotificationStatus int,
    @BidStatus int,
    @BidAmount int,
    @ProductId int
AS    
    DECLARE @highestBid int;
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        SET @highestBid = (SELECT Max(wf_bid.BidAmount) AS HighestBitAmount 
                           FROM wf_bid 
                           WHERE wf_bid.ProductId = @ProductId)

        IF @highestBid is NULL OR @highestBid < @BidAmount
        BEGIN
            UPDATE wf_bid 
            SET BidStatus = '1' 
            WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP 1 id 
                        FROM [wf_bid] 
                        WHERE BidAmount = (SELECT MAX(BidAmount) 
                                           FROM [wf_bid] 
                                           WHERE ProductId = @ProductId 
                                             AND ClientId = @ClientId))


            INSERT INTO wf_bid (BidType, ClientId, BidDate, EmailNotificationStatus, BidStatus)
            VALUES (@BidType, @ClientId, @BidDate, @EmailNotificationStatus, @BidStatus)
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Everything looks okay to me. But once I run this, table is getting locked. No other query on the table works (I think it is because transaction is not getting committed).

Can anyone point out what is wrong with this query? And how can I unlock the table?

Comment: Is this stored procedure getting completed after execution? If not, what is the time taken by update and insert statements on table: wf_bid?

Comment: What are the possible values for `BidStatus`? If it's only, effectively "this is the highest" or not then this is data that can easily be *derived* and doesn't need to be stored. This in turn means that you could just do a simple `INSERT ... SELECT <new bid data> WHERE NOT EXISTS (<higher bid>)` as a single statement rather than this procedural code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But once I run this, table is getting locked

This may be due to update taking many locks,which in turn may be due to predicate not being sargable. Though this update locks(U) lock will be released as soon as the predicate is not matched.You will experience blocking

One more reason ,why this update may block your whole table is when this transaction acquires more than 5000 locks..

another  reason can be when your transaction fails after committing so many rows and it has to do a lot of rollback work

Above are the reasons ,i could think of,where you can experience table is locked feeling

to troubleshoot that,you will need to check lockings blokcings using below query

```
select resource_type,resource_Database_id,
request_mode,request_type,request_Status,request_session_id
 from sys.dm_tran_locks 
 where request_session_id=<<your update session id>>
```

also you are accessing table many times,for getting max.you can rewrite it like below

```
;with cte
as
(
select top (1) with ties  id,bidstatus from 
wf_bid 
where ProductId=@ProductId and ClientId=@ClientId)
order by 
row_number() over (partition by id order by bid_Amount desc)
)
update cte
set bidstatus=1
```

Comment: @Athul:Updated,it should be `request_session_id`